# Can I use an RX6R's PWM and SBus outputs simultaneously?

Tags: flight-controller, receiver, frsky, sbus

I'm looking at options to build a pan/tilt system for FPV. The FC that I have available has only 4 servo outputs, and the airplane has 3 servos. Given this, I can't run the pan and tilt through the FC. Can I use the PWM outputs on the FrSky RX6R to control the 3 pan/tilt/retract servos and use the SBus output to run the FC?

Comment: Good question! I'm not sure, as I'm a budget FlySky pilot, but I think the answer is no. Most RC RXs I know of only allow one output type at a time, i.e. either PWM/PPM or digital protocol. But I may be wrong about FrSky specifically in some way.